# Implementing a simple 1/s integration in PSCAD while it only offers 1/sT

Tags: remote-control, time, integrator

So I'm doing some modelling in a power systems simulation software (PSCAD)

I'm using the integrator block in that software.

Now unlike SIMULINK PSCAD doesn't offer a \$ 1 \over s \$ block but offers a \$1 \over s*T\$ block where \$ T \$ is the time constant.

I just want a simple integration operation done, i.e:

When I input

$$
A*sin(100t)
$$

I want to get

$$
-(A/100)*cos(100t) 
$$
What should I set the time constant \$ T \$ to get this basic result?

Comment: You answered your own question- You want 1/s, so T=1.

Comment: Thanks. I just realised that shortly after positng. I had a long day at work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$\frac{1}{sT}\$ is just the same as \$\frac{1}{s}\frac{1}{T}\$

So set T = 1 or use it to set the gain of your integrator